# Arguments inside sed loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, sed

Im trying to understand sed command and loops.
I need to take part of the text (20 lines) and append it to the csv with the file name.
here is my code

```
for i in ~/mspl/*.doc
do 
    catdoc "$i" > auto.txt
    sed -e '1,20!d' auto.txt > auto1.txt
    sed -e '1s/^/"$i" ;/' auto1.txt > auto2.txt
    sed -e '20s/$/~/' auto2.txt > auto3.txt
    cat auto3.txt >> lines.csv
done
```

the problem is that my second "i" argument doesn't convert to the file name in csv.

in the line

```
sed -e '1s/^/"$i" ;/' auto1.txt > auto2.txt
```

Please tell what is my mistake here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that variables are not expanded within single quotes `'`. Use double quotes instead `"`:

```
# this is assuming you did want to add explicit " around your $i
sed -e "1s/^/\"$i\" ;/" auto1.txt > auto2.txt
```

If your double-quoted string needs to contain explicit double quotes, you have to escape them (`\"`). If using double quotes is not an option (e.g. if you have a very complex command with multiple levels of quoting already) you can always exit the quoting around your variable:

```
sed -e '1s/^/"'$i'" ;/' auto1.txt > auto2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it useful to run this script with the `-x` setting, to see what's actually going on. (Just do `set -x`.)

But just to be blunt, what's going on is that your `$i` is inside single quotes, so it doesn't get expanded.