# SED command inside a loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, sed, do-loops

Hello: I have a lot of files called `test-MR3000-1.txt` to `test-MR4000-1.nt`, where the number in the name changes by 100 (i.e. I have 11 files),

```
$ ls test-MR*
test-MR3000-1.nt  test-MR3300-1.nt  test-MR3600-1.nt  test-MR3900-1.nt
test-MR3100-1.nt  test-MR3400-1.nt  test-MR3700-1.nt  test-MR4000-1.nt
test-MR3200-1.nt  test-MR3500-1.nt  test-MR3800-1.nt
```

and also a file called `resonancia.kumac` which in a couple on lines contains the string `XXXX`.

```
$ head resonancia.kumac
close 0
hist/delete 0
vect/delete *
h/file 1 test-MRXXXX-1.nt
sigma MR=XXXX
```

I want to execute a `bash` file which substitutes the strig `XXXX` in a file by a set of numbers obtained from the command `ls *MR* | cut -b 8-11`.

I found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402121/arguments-inside-sed-loop) in which there are some suggestions. I try my own code

```
for i in `ls *MR* | cut -b 8-11`; do
    sed -e "s/XXXX/$i/" resonancia.kumac >> proof.kumac
done
```

however, in the substitution the numbers are surrounded by sigle qoutes (e.g. `'3000'`).

**Q:** What should I do to avoid the single quote in the set of numbers? Thank you.

Comment: Don't ever use ls this way. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ...also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you for the advise! I didn't know

Comment: ...also, you haven't described your problem in a way that lets anyone else reproduce it, so I don't see how anyone could help you with it. Someone needs to know the filenames you're using, the actual contents of the input files, the actual output you're getting, etc. If you can provide a standalone script that creates the necessary files and inputs and then reproduces the problem with those inputs it creates -- thus, something that reproduces the problem starting from nothing -- that would be helpful.

Comment: As it stands, the script is wasting effort because it edits the original file over the new file with the same pattern XXXX being replaced by the MR number.  So, the net result of the loop is that the last substitution is the only effective substitution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In fact, the `bash` substitute all the numbers, but it writes `MR='3000'` instead of `MR=3000`.

Comment: @Dox So you want to make 11 copies of `resonance.kumac`? One for each MR type file?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, but each copy have a different value of `XXXX`, and they are saved into a single file `proof.kumac`

Comment: The code you have provided would not insert single quotes, and it works fine for me. Please copy-paste this code and try it again, without any ad hoc changes from that post you mentioned.

Comment: ...by the way -- the reproducer I gave at the beginning of my answer is what you _should_ have included in your question.

Comment: So the `proof.kumac` will just be the lines `h/file 1 test-MRXXXX-1.nt` and `sigma MR=XXXX` repeated for different numbers? You should post what `proof.kumac` should look like in the end.

Comment: @thatotherguy don't know why, but you where right! I try the code once again and worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @Dox While the original code didn't have the bug you asked here about, it _did_ have other bugs. Do consider taking advantage of the improvements offered here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reproducer for the environment described:

```
for ((i=3000; i<=4000; i+=100)); do
  touch test-MR${i}-1.nt
done
cat >resonancia.kumac <<'EOF'
close 0
hist/delete 0
vect/delete *
h/file 1 test-MRXXXX-1.nt
sigma MR=XXXX
EOF
```

This is a script which will run inside that environment:

```
content="$(<resonancia.kumac)"
for f in *MR*; do
    substring=${f:7:3}
    echo "${content//XXXX/$substring}"
done >proof.kumac
```

...and the output looks like so:

```
close 0
hist/delete 0
vect/delete *
h/file 1 test-MR300-1.nt
sigma MR=300
```

There are no quotes anywhere in this output; the problem described is not reproduced.

Comment: can you explian `echo "${content//XXXX/$substring}"` and `${f:7:3}` ?

Answer (score 1):

or if it could be perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@ls = glob('*MR*');

open (FILE, 'resonancia.kumac') || die("not good\n");

@cont = <FILE>;

$f = shift(@ls);
$f =~ /test-MR([0-9]*)-1\.nt/;
$nr = $1;

@out = ();
foreach $l (@cont){
    if($l =~ s/XXXX/$nr/){
        $f = shift(@ls);
        $f =~ /test-MR([0-9]*)-1\.nt/;
        $nr = $1;
    }
    push @out, $l;
}

close FILE;
open FILE, '>resonancia.kumac' || die("not good\n");
print FILE @out;
```

That would replace the first XXXX with the first filename, what seemed to be the question before change.